# How to properly use CoreData validation & error framework?

Tags: validation, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've created a model in Xcode, and for various attributes I have minimum & maximum values defined and that are enforced by coreData at runtime.

I'm using NSManagedObject validateValue:forKey:error to check for user input values.

I was a bit disappointed to see that the localized error message is not specific, and I get a "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1620)" for too small values and a "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1610)" for too large values.

It's written in the coreData documentation that "you can localize most aspects of a managed object model, including entity and property names and error messages". Unfortunately it's not very detailed on how you implement it for error messages.

So How do you customize error message ? How do you localize them ?
Is it possible to customize it in a way where it will mentioned the reference value ex: "Value should be lower than %@" or "Value should be higher than %@" ?

Answer (score 0):

To customize the errors as you want, you will need to implement custom NSManagedObject subclasses and then implement the validation methods for each attribute to return the errors you wish.

Comment: the fact is that the validation routines are already existing and are quite generic, I don't wan't to customize each of the nsmanaged objects when I can define min max values straight in the xcode coredata model designer. Either I find a way to access these values, or I might end up redefining my owns by using custom min/max userinfo values for each attributes...

Comment: The errors themselves are defined in CocoaErrors.h. 1620 is NSValidationNumberTooSmallError and 1610 is NSValidationNumberTooLargeError. You could also make a dictionary to return the enumeration name. The numerical codes are supposed to be for programmers and textual errors for end users. That is why the textual errors often contain only vague reports of an error.

Comment: Is this required simply to change the text on the error message that pops up when a non-optional attribute is left blank? Or is there an easier way to change that?